# How to implement a deep-tree-set algorithm using fold?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, scheme

This is the pseudocode for a function that will modify a specific node on a tree given a path and a new value:

```
path_set val path tree = 
    | empty? path -> val
    | otherwise -> set (path_set val (tail path) (get tree (head path))) tree
```

For example,

```
path_set 50 [1 1] [[1 1] [1 1]] = [[1 1] [1 50]]
```

How can this algorithm be implemented using fold?

Comment: A fold is probably not the best way to do this.  Folds are usually used for iterative application, not recursive.  You also haven't defined what kind of tree, what that path of all ones represents, etc.  You also probably would want to implement the tree as its own data type, since lists can't be arbitrarily nested in Haskell, branch has to have the same depth, so to speak.

Comment: If you want to do this with a fold, you need a zipper. Actually, the LYAH tutorial has a page on zippers and addresses almost this exact question: moving through a tree according to a list of directions. http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers So, you can do it with a fold but it probably wont be cleaner or faster, since the code you gave is already pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as nobody answered, here is my solution:

```
(λ (λ (λ (foldr (λ (λ (set B (get 0 A) (get 1 A)))) C ((λ (λ (foldl (λ (λ (conc B (list ((list (A (if (eq (len B) 0) C (get (get 0 (last B)) (get 1 (last B))))))))))) (list) B))) B A)))))
```

In lambda calculus with bruijn indices encoded by alphabetically ascending letters and conc-lists.

It is really unoptimal, but works fine for my use case as it almost always reduced in compile time anyway (you almost always have the path defined when you want to call `set`).